# BIService could not be acquired! while hyperion reports are running

Tags: hyperion

BIService could not be acquired! while hyperion reports are running.

logs-

06 feb 2024 06:19:46,296

 PAX LL EN CONEX/PAX LL EN CONEX to Event Service for Retry Processing]]>

restarted the services but again after few hours getting same error.